# Convert string of hexadecimal color to hexadecimal format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a function that takes a musical note and converts it to a hexadecimal color.

```
const colorFromNote = note => `0x${note}${note}${note}`
```

For example, C4 returns `0xc4c4c4`. However, this does not work with [Three.js](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Color) because it needs an actual hexadecimal parameter, not a string of one.

All of the other answers are for generating hex codes from color names. I just need to convert a string of a hex to the hex itself.

Comment: `parseInt('0xc4c4c4')`

Comment: `THREE.Color()` (and its method `.set()`) accepts such CSS string `'#c4c4c4'`

Answer (score 0):

to convert a string to a hexadecimal number, use parseInt

```
parseInt(hexString, 16);
```

to convert a number to hexadecimal string (the opposite):

```
yourNumber.toString(16);
```

Comment: that gives me 12895428